# Proof: A channel is entanglement breaking if it separates maximally entangled states

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

I'm working my way through Mark M. Wilde's Quantum Information Theory (2nd edition) and am stuck on a proof regarding entanglement breaking channels (Exercise 4.6.2)

> Prove that a channel $\mathcal{N}_{A\to B}$ is entanglement-breaking if $\left(\text{id}_R\otimes\mathcal{N}_{A\to B}\right)\left(\Phi_{RA}\right)$ is a separable state.

Here $\Phi_{RA}$ is the maximally entangled state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\sum_j \vert j\rangle_R \vert j\rangle_A$ and $\text{id}_R$ represents the identity channel on reference system $R$.

It is important to note that a Kraus operator representation for entanglement-breaking channels hasn't been introduced yet at this point in the text, and neither has the fact that such Kraus operators are rank $1$. Only the definition of entanglement-breaking channels has been presented, as follows.

> An entanglement-breaking channel is a quantum channel $\mathcal{N}_{A\to B}$ such that the channel $\text{id}_R \otimes \mathcal{N}_{A \to B}$ takes any state $\rho_{RA}$ to a separable state, where $R$ is a reference system of arbitrary size.

How do I go about proving the statement? I think the linearity of $\mathcal{N}_{A \to B}$ and that the set of separable states forms a convex set has to be used, but apart from that I am stuck. Any hints or help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the Choi-Jamiolkowski isomorphism.

Comment: see [Why are entanglement breaking channels, defined as $Φ(ρ)=\sum_a {\rm Tr}(μ(a)ρ)σ_a$, entanglement breaking?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16565/55)